# Hibernate: ManyToMany links are being deleted without CascadeType.REMOVE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, cascade

I have such database tables:

[image: Database tables]

And these are the foreign key constraints:

```sql
-- If current variable is being referenced by another variable, restrict deletion
ALTER TABLE variable_variable
    ADD CONSTRAINT variable_variable_variable_id_to_fkey
        FOREIGN KEY (variable_id_to) REFERENCES variable (id)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT;

-- If current variable reference other variable, delete its link by cascade
ALTER TABLE variable_variable
    ADD CONSTRAINT variable_variable_variable_id_from_fkey
        FOREIGN KEY (variable_id_from) REFERENCES variable (id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So, if I have references like:

1. `Other Variable -> Current Variable`, then `Current Variable` deletion has to be prohibited
2. `Current Variable -> Other Variable`, then `Current Variable` deletion should also remove link from `Current Variable` to `Other Variable` on cascade (links are stored in `variable_variable` table).

Here is my Hibernate entity for `variable` table.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "variable")
@Getter
@Setter(PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@DynamicUpdate
public class Variable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private VariableId id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "variable_variable",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id_from"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id_to")
    )
    private Set<Variable> variables = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "variable_variable",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id_to", updatable = false, insertable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id_from", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    )
    // this collection is readonly and never updates
    private Set<Variable> inverseVariables = new HashSet<>();
    
    ...
}
```

So, `ManyToMany` relationships are on the owning side and I have no `CascadeType.REMOVE`.
But if I call `EntityManager.remove(variable)`, those SQL statements are being invoked:

```sql
Query:["delete from variable_variable where variable_id_to=?"]
Params:[(7fbbf360-74a0-48db-a1e2-d3b1ab0a869f)]

Query:["delete from variable_variable where variable_id_from=?"]
Params:[(7fbbf360-74a0-48db-a1e2-d3b1ab0a869f)]

Query:["delete from variable where id=?"]
Params:[(7fbbf360-74a0-48db-a1e2-d3b1ab0a869f)]
```

Hibernate deletes links from `variable_variable` prematurely. However, that's not the behavior I need. It breaks the whole idea of complex database constraints in `variable_variable` table I described earlier. So, I don't want Hibernate to delete anything from there on its own basis.

I managed to solve this problem with native query:

```java
em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM variable WHERE id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", variableId)
            .executeUpdate();
```

Anyway, I'd like not to introduce native queries. Is it possible to tell Hibernate not to delete `variable_variable` rows on `Variable` removing?

Comment: If you delete one side of a many to many mapping the records on the mapping table must be deleted. That's the correct behavior

Comment: @SimonMartinelli is there a way to tune this behavior?

Comment: No this behavior works as expected. If you remove a Variable then the record in the mapping table must be deleted otherwise you'll get a foreign key violation

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have cascade delete constraint in database for `variable_id_from` and restrict for `variable_id_to`. That's the behaviour I expect. If `Variable` has any other variables that reference to it, then deletion is prohibited. I could just execute native query as I described, but I wonder is it possible to tell Hibernate that I don't want additional queries for links removal

Comment: If you are using Hibernate you shouldn't use cascade delete on the database foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with `mappedBy` inverse reference. Look at the code snippet below:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "variable")
@Getter
@Setter(PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@DynamicUpdate
public class Variable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private VariableId id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "variable_variable",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id_from"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id_to")
    )
    private Set<Variable> variables = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "variables")
    // this collection is readonly and never updates
    private Set<Variable> inverseVariables = new HashSet<>();
    
    ...
}
```

Now when I call `em.remove(variable)`, those SQL statements are generated:

```sql
Query:["delete from variable_variable where variable_id_from=?"]
Params:[(7fbbf360-74a0-48db-a1e2-d3b1ab0a869f)]

Query:["delete from variable where id=?"]
Params:[(7fbbf360-74a0-48db-a1e2-d3b1ab0a869f)]
```

Only `Current Variable` and references `Current Variable -> Other Variable` are being deleted. If there references `Other Variable -> Current Variable`, then deletion fails due to database integrity violation. Just what I need